# Blockchain linking algorithm

Tags: blockchain

Why does new block include only parent's block hash instead of hash of it's all previous blocks calculated using e.g. merkle tree algorithm?

Comment: What would be the benefit of such approach?

Answer (score 1):

Because the parent hash is already based on the previous parent hash, and so on, it effectively *does* include all of them. A merkle tree is a commitment to all of them, this does the same thing. It would just make generating the block header harder before the miner can even start mining, so there would be no benefit.